# C# interop to lower level other than c\c++

Tags: c#, interop, integration-testing

Given the fact that I need in specific parts of my projects, 
to interop / interact a .net `c#` code with a code that's within a `dll` produced by an unmanaged language:
which  language **other than c\c++** has good compatibility and is as fast or preferably faster?
I have searched and found few ( looks promising) less popular names I couldn't decide on any of them as I have no clue how to if it's possible at all to  interact with their `dll`.
`Haskell`, `Rust`, `D`, `Fortran`, `Nim`... **and more**..

Did you try to implement this approach with any of them?

Comment: .NET can interop with _Managed_ (.NET), _COM_, and _native_ (C, C++) DLLs.  So the _language_ is not as important as the _platform_ that they use.

Comment: In any case, I'm voting to close as too broad.

Answer (score -1):

Use C++/CLI. This give you an bridge with managed and unmanaged in the best performance possible.

Comment: can you please explain your answer, as i was refering to question one's experience with more than testing c++ did u by any chance get to try some other language ?

Comment: or you're just saying ..no mater if i will use limbo gingo or dingo as an other laguage to interact with, i should use a `C++/CLI` as "the man in the middle", and that would perform better than Platform Invoke (`[DllImport]`) ?